# Eclipse can not catch up the external CSS

Tags: html, css, jsp

When I use external css as the screen, the jsp page dont now the bootstrap css.

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to using `<link href="../bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Comment: already tried bro can not.

Answer (score 0):

your bootstrap file are located "WebContent/bootstrap/css" index file located main path.

use this path

```
<link href="../WebContent/bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```